# ¿alguien sabe por qué no recibo respuesta cuando leo el codigo de qr en whatsapp-web.js adjunto mi index.js

Tags: php, nodejs, whatsapp

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**texto en negritaFDDDDDDDDGDSFDSFSDFD**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega el código como texto.

Comment: Que version de WhatsApp.web.js estas usando?
Hay un problema con la reciente version, valida este issues y actualiza segun dice https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/issues/2521 saludos.